# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'onTouch' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android

The android developer page says onTouch is part of API level 1, and I'm using API level 17 (other stackoverflow answers to similar questions suggested increasing the API level to ensure that all the necessary packages are available for your application).

Here is my activity_main.xml code: (The first ImageView is the one with the error)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/graph" 
        android:onTouch="listenTouch"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <!-- <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send" 
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:layout_toLeftOf= "@id/edit_message"/> -->
 <!--    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Image" /> -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/button_send" 
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:text="Submit Points" 
        android:onClick="beginTSP"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

</RelativeLayout> -->
```

This is my MainActivity.Java code:

```
package com.myfirstproject.test;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import client.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.myfirstproject.test.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    public void listenTouch(View v,MotionEvent event){
        int x = (int)(event.getX());
        int y = (int)(event.getY());
        City tempCity = new City(x,y);
        TourManager.addCity(tempCity);
        //return true;
    }
    public void beginTSP(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        String message = "0";
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

What I noticed is that when I change "onTouch" to "onClick" that error goes away (a different error occurs since onClick calls listenTouch which takes a MotionEvent as an arg, but onClick only accepts View as an arg).

I've updated my SDK, and I set my min API to 17 and target API to 17. I've also made sure that I'm using Android 4.2.2 (when I right-clicked my project, clicked "Properties, and then clicked Android, Android 4.2.2 was selected).

My Compiler Compliance level is 1.6. Interestingly, when I tried to change it, I got an error saying something like "Android wants compiler compliance 5.0 or 6.0, yours is 1.7" (it was more formal than that, but it basically said that), so I couldn't update my compiler compliance to 1.7, but I do not see why this would cause onTouch to not function properly?

In case it is useful, here is my Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myfirstproject.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.myfirstproject.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myfirstproject.test.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.myfirstproject.test.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myfirstproject.test.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <WebView android:id="@+id/pic_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
        </WebView>
    </LinearLayout>

</manifest>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `android:onTouch` does not exist. It is enough to use the `OnTouchListener` which can be added to every view easily by the setter method `setOnTouchListener`.

In your case:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.myimage).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int x = (int)(event.getX());
            int y = (int)(event.getY());
            City tempCity = new City(x,y);
            TourManager.addCity(tempCity);
            return true;
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! btw, I added "return true" to your proposed onTouch, is that correct?

Comment: oh yeah, I missed that. true as a return means that you "consumed" the event and that this touch event shouldn't be delegated to another view/activity.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute does not exist,It's nothing to do with the SDK or the level. True if the event was handled, false otherwise.